# I am getting and error in chrome as 400 bad request for preflight. Angular + Azure Functions

Tags: angular, azure, azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions to host apis and Angular as front end. I am facing issues with Chrome PreFlight [OPTIONS] request which gets 400 Bad request Error.

[image: Screenshot of Request in Chome]

It works on my Dev Machine. I do not see any pre flight errors.

Comment: Have you added the host where angular front end locates to [CORS list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#cors)?

Comment: I added that and I added * in Cors but still fails..

Comment: On more digging I found that when I add Authorization bearer token in the header I get this error...

Comment: I added the entry and it worked....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to go to Platform Features tab -> Click on CORS and add your FrontEnd URL to the list of Allowed Origins.

[image]

Comment: I tried that it did not work..

On more digging I found that when I add Authorization bearer token in the header I get this error...

Comment: If you add * to CORS  list you have to remove all the other URLs. Otherwise neither of them are applicable

Comment: @user1387192 Please accept Naren's answer to close your question.